# FilesystemAdapter could not be converted to string Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a photo upload form which goes to this code

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|max:3000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();

        $usersname = $user->username;
       $file = $request->file('image');
      $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $path = Storage::disk('uploads');

        $filename = $usersname . '.' . $ext;

        if (Storage::disk('uploads')->has($filename)) {
            Storage::delete($filename);
        }
       Storage::disk('uploads')->put($filename, File::get($file));

       $resizedImg = Image::make($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename)->resize(200,200)->save($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

        return redirect()->route('profile.index', 
                ['username' => Auth::user()->username]);
    }
```

When I make this code execute it gives me this error

```
ErrorException in ProfileController.php line 71:
Object of class Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter could not be converted to string
```

line 71 is the line beginning with $resizedImg but the photo does save to the correct directory just not resized.

I defined uploads in the filesystems.php file as following

```
 'disks' => [

        'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => public_path('/uploads'),
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$path` contents driver in it, but you're trying to use it as string, that's the problem. Try to use something like:

```
$path = '/uploads';
```